# What is the term for varying types of selection, and why are most apps either one/the other with no setting

Tags: gui-design

This might be asked before, but I'm trying to create a feature for my design app that supports both methods of selection in this way. One mode should select all items that the bounding box even touches a little bit of the item in question, it selects it. Example here (bounding box is black, green is selected, red is omitted):
[image]

The other type of selection is more strict, and only selects ones that are completely within the box.
[image]

Additionally, most apps that I found are usually one or the other (either that or I haven't found the setting because I don't know how to look for it). For instance, Illustrator defaults as the first option, but some apps like Solidworks in 2D mode default as the 2nd option. Despite this being a really simple feature, it can severely improve or otherwise hamper some simple tasks; like if the objects are really close to one another, the 2nd option is better for precision. Apologies if this is actually a duplicate, I have no idea how to explain this to Google. Thanks y'all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Window Selection / Crossing Selection

Interesting question!

This was one of the main differences between the old Freehand and Illustrator. While Freehand only selected objects within the marquee selection, Illustrator does so by just touching them.

In *Autodesk* applications (*AutoCad*, *3ds Max*) there's a clear difference and name between both selection types:

> - Drag from left to right to select all objects that are entirely
>   enclosed in the selection rectangle or lasso (**window selection**).
> - Drag from right to left to select all objects that are crossed by the selection rectangle or lasso (**crossing selection**).

By the way, a very interesting workaround.

*Source [Autocad Help](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-lt/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2019/ENU/AutoCAD-LT/files/GUID-243E4DD0-8947-4905-AFE2-BE9B903A8C3F-htm.html)*

Comment: thank you so much, I've been looking for this option for ages, and this helps so much. it really is a shame it doesn't exist in more apps; I really feel like very many apps would benefit from this option.